# How to use django migrate without confirmation

Tags: django, migrate, django-migrations

I am using django 1.8.

When using Django's `manage.py migrate` command, user confirmation is needed when a model as been deleted. The `--noinput` parameter can avoid user confirmation, but then migration does not remove models.

How can I use `manage.py migrate` in a script, and remove old models?

And, I know, it can be dangerous.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I just tested with Django 1.8. Migrate deleted the model without requiring confirmation, whether or not I used `--noinput`. I don't understand why it requires confirmation for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect - `--noinput` still runs all migrations, including those which remove models.